# my code runs perfectly, but as soon as I submit it, I get a compilation error. Can anyone help me? Included the code below

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int t=in.nextInt();
    int sum=0;
    
    for(int i=0; i<t; i++)
    {
      int n=in.nextInt();
    
      for(int j=1; j<n; j++)
      {
        if(n%j==0)
          sum=sum+j;
      }
      
      if(n==sum)
        System.out.println("true")
      
      else
        System.out.println("false");
    }
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Typically the error will point to exactly where the problem is. Please edit your question to include the compilation error

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a semi-colon on line `System.out.println("true")`.
I would recommend you to use any IDE to avoid these kind of errors.

Comment: thank you so much! the platform still says my answer is wrong. Trying to find if a number is a perfect number or not.  tried with custom inputs as well, runs perfectly, is there any reason why this is happening?

Comment: What do you mean by perfect number?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is just syntax error at end of instruction using semicolon

You need to close the

```
if(n==sum)
    System.out.println("true");  // semicolon
```

Comment: thank you so much! the platform still says my answer is wrong. Trying to find if a number is a perfect number or not. tried with custom inputs as well, runs perfectly, is there any reason why this is happening?